# how do i access the document dom object in ejs?

Tags: javascript, express, ejs

I am trying show a list of participants when the user clicks on the button.But each time i end up with an error ""document is not defined".(Please don't give me jquery!!).

```
<% var bt = document.getElementById("bt");
        bt.addEventListener('onclick',function(){
    var chatbox = document.getElementsByClassName('parti');
    var msg = document.createElement('div');
    msg.setAttribute('class', 'participants');
    msg.textContent('Participant \n\n\n'); %>
<%= chatbox.appendChild(msg); %>
<% }); %>
```

Comment: Your template is rendered on the server, not in the browser, so you don't have access to the DOM in your templates.

Comment: @robertklep so what do i do for setting eventListeners on the client-side?

Comment: Client side JS code (regular `<script>` tags).

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
bt.addEventListener('onclick',function(){
```

With this:

```
bt.addEventListener('click',function(){
```

When we use addEventListener we don't need to use prefix 'on' for even name.

Also, you have used getElementsByClassName and for this you need to iterate over array, so use:

`<%= chatbox[0].appendChild(msg); %>`